# What may Apache IoTDB perform if only one datanode is configured in the cluster version?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I currently configured the cluster of Apache IoTDB and I used session pool to connect all nodes, but if only one of the datanodes is configured, will it have any impact on the use of IoTDB? I installed 3 datanodes and confignodes, but only one of the nodes is set up when using IoTDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only one datanode connection is configured, then if this datanode is unavailable, the session will not be connected in Apache IoTDB. Thererfore, it is still recommended to configure all the nodes in the cluster of IoTDB.